# Oracle Enterprise Manager 11g Database Control - Agent Unreachable

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This is a single instance DB. Can Login to OEM 11g DB Control.  However, on the Home page it shows Agent Unreachable.

I check the status in  $ORACLE_HOME/bin with emctl status agent.  The output is "Agent not running".  But , start and stop commands are not available in that path.  So, I cannot do a emctl start agent.

The Oracle docs mentions that we should start / stop the agent from  $AGENT_HOME/bin  path. However, I do not know the AGENT_HOME path. How can I find it?

Thank You.